# How can ı replace the whitespace to random number in string

Tags: python, string, random, whitespace

I am trying to change whitespaces to random number and number must be between the (0,9) in phyton ex. "hello world" to "hello6world" or "ı am the king" to "ı5am6the8king"

```py
import random
text = input("Text :")
text.replace(" ", str((random.randint(0, 9))))
print(text)
```

here's my code but it didn't change the whitespace to number.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: enctext.replace(" ", (random.randint(0, 9)))

Comment: Then please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72204614/edit) to show this, because questions that are not asking about some specific code are off-topic

Comment: now is this okey

Comment: This is better now, although in future please also say the specific problem you are having (i.e. say something like "but all of the numbers within the string are the same").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
text = input("Text :")
print(text.replace(" ", str((random.randint(0, 9)))))
```

The above code prints the replace query used as it will print the returned value of
`Text.replace()`automatically.

If you `print(Text)` as in original code it will print the original string saved in the variable `Text` as strings are immutable. Instead you can also save `text.replace(" ", str((random.randint(0, 9))))` in a different variable (let `x`) and then `print(x)`.

Either directly printing the replace query or saving it in a different variable and printing it will solve the issue of filling whitespaces with integer.

*Though this will apply only the same random number generated to all the whitespaces such as making the string as "i5am5the5king" instead of "i5am6the8king".You can rectify this by traversing the string and assigning whitespaces as a randint to a new string by doing

```
import random
text = input("Text :")
x=""
for i in range(len(text)):
    if text[i]==" ":
        x+=str((random.randint(0, 9)))
    else:
        x+=text[i]
print(x)
```

This will print a string with whitespaces replaced as random numbers such as  "i8am7the9king" instead of "i2am2the2king".

Answer (score 0):

```
For letter in myString: 
  If letter = ' ':
    #Replace with random
```